# Composite Pattern in a non part whole hierarchy

Tags: design-patterns

I'm following a course on Design Patterns, using the book of GoF.
I've been confronted with the following question:

> "Would you use the composite pattern if you did not have a part-whole
>   hierarchy? In other words, if only a few objects have children and
>   almost everything else in your collection is a leaf (a leaf that has
>   no children), would you still use the composite pattern to model these
>   objects?"

I thought the answer was no, since you don't have a good tree structure and composites purpose is to be able to ignore the difference between leaves and composites.

However, somebody else had this answer:

> "This design pattern would certainly be a candidate for use in this
>   case. Even though most of the objects are leaves, those leaves can be
>   part referenced and organized by a composite object. In fact, this is
>   the way most composite designs are implemented, with one composite
>   object grouping multiple types of leaf objects"

Comment: i think this is heavily opinion-based

Comment: This reminds me why I despise school so much. A parallel universe to the real world